# NGINX try_files with name as the last word in the $uri

Tags: nginx, location, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've got an nginx on my server and I am trying to get it to open the file '`/config/www/pp1/index.php`' for address https://example.com/pp1 and '`/config/www/interpreter/index.html`' for https://example.com/interpreter. Furthermore all things like https://example.com/interpreter/res/docs should fire up '`/config/www/interpreter/res/docs.html`'. I have made many attempts. Currently my default config file in /site-confs looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name kni.mini.pw.edu.pl;

        # Path for SSL config/key/certificate
        ssl_certificate /config/keys/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/cert.key;

        location / {
                proxy_read_timeout    90;
                proxy_connect_timeout 90;
                proxy_redirect        off;
                proxy_pass http://kni_website;
                proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header      Host $host;
        }

         location /pp1 {
                root /config/www;
                index index.html index.htm index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ index.php $uri/index.php /config/www/pp1/index.php index.php; #/index.php?$args =404;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        # With php5-cgi alone:
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                        # With php5-fpm:
                        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                }
        }
         location /interpreter {
                if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)" ) {
                        set  $last_path_component  $1;
                }
                root /config/www;
                index index.html index.htm index.php $last_path_component.html;
                try_files /interpreter/res/$last_path_component.html $uri.html $uri.html $uri $uri/ /index.html index.php /$uri.html  /index.php?$args =404;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        # With php5-cgi alone:
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                        # With php5-fpm:
                        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                }
        }

}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        listen 443 ssl;

        root /config/www;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name _;

        ssl_certificate /config/keys/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/cert.key;

        client_max_body_size 0;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # With php5-cgi alone:
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        }
}
```

Quite frankly, I thought I knew what I was doing, however right now I am pretty certain that the location block `location /interpreter` is not being checked at all and the insides of `location /pp1` are causing some crazy mumbo-jumbo.

Please help a newbie in need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that `try_files` will process its *file* elements within the current context, so you cannot handle your `.html` and `.php` URIs in the same statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

One solution is to use a named location to split the `try_files` statement into two. First to test `$uri`, `$uri.html` and `$uri/index.html`, then a second to test `$uri.php` and `$uri/index.php`.

For example:

```
root /path/to/root;

location /foo {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html @php;
    location ~* ^(.*)\.php$ { return 301 $1; }
}
location @php {
    try_files $uri.php $uri/index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass  ...;
    ...
}
```

The `location ~* ^(.*)\.php$` block is added to handle URIs that end with `.php` correctly. The simplest solution is to redirect them to a URI with the `.php` removed.

Comment: Thank you! It works now, however I have to navigate to https://example.com/pp1/ (with the slash at the end) - it doesn't work when I navigate to  https://example.com/pp1 (without the slash) is there a way like a rewrite to remedy this?

Comment: I meant `https://example.com/pp1/` and I want it to be accessible from `https://example.com/pp1` (no slash at the end)

Comment: Strangely `curl -I https://kni.mini.pw.edu.pl/pp1` shows it redirecting to `http`. The configuration in your question or my answer shouldn't do that. Is this server terminating the SSL connection?

Comment: I am behind a proxy administered by someone else. I've got no access to how he / she handles the ssl certbots. My problem is, however, independent of that, I do believe (or is it not??). I would like the the uri : `https://kni.mini.pw.edu.pl/pp1` be handled like `https://kni.mini.pw.edu.pl/pp1/`. The first one is always treated as if it were just `https://kni.mini.pw.edu.pl`. Could the problem be connected with the fact that under location / resides a docker with wordpress?

Comment: Are you still using `$uri/` as one of the file terms in your `try_files` statement?