# Remove .php in url with nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

Im not a SysAdmin so i don't really understand how its work to do what I want.
But I have a PHP website with .php file and I want to remove the .php in URL.

On apache its easier but nginx is better so i want to know how to do this on nginx.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.com www.xx.com;
    root /var/www/xx;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Thank you all

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/21911610/10059628 answer your question?

Comment: hello no i don't have any file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.tld.conf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NGINX try\_files does not pass to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917213/nginx-try-files-does-not-pass-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

Add `$uri.php$is_args$query_string` to the end of `/` location:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
}
```